# iPad landscape dimensions issue

Tags: ipad, swift, landscape, dimensions

I have application using Landscape orientation only. I have set Device orientation to "Landscape Left" only in project properties. Every controller has Orientation set to Landscape too.

In IOS emulator works all right, width of screen is greater than height, views frames and bounds are as shown. No matter if I run "iPad 2", "iPad Air" and IOS 7 or 8.

If I run it on physically iPad Air, all dimensions are switched as if they are in Portrait mode. Bounds, frames, screen sizes are switched as if begin of screen is top right.

I'd like to do something to say to iPad rotate screen dimensions. I can do some workarounds, but it has another side effect, witch I cannot change. I'm using animation:

```
      UIView.animateWithDuration(0.75, animations: {
            UIView.setAnimationCurve(UIViewAnimationCurve.EaseInOut);
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated:false);
            UIView.setAnimationTransition(UIViewAnimationTransition.CurlUp, forView: self.navigationController!.view, cache: false);
        } );
```

In simulator runs CurlUp perfectly (from right bottom corner to top left), but on iPad animates from bottom left to top right.

Do you have any simple solution, please?

Comment: OK, it seems as a big problem. So, have you solution, where one page moves up (down) and instead her appears a new page? In landscape mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue solved itself. I have got a new device, iPad 3 > iPad Air 2 and issue doesn't appear here : )